# Creating a dataframe from a scraped character vector

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I am trying to create a dataframe that has the columns: First name, Last name, Party, State, Member ID. Here is my code

```
library('rvest')

candidate_url <- 'https://www.congress.gov/help/field-values/member-bioguide-ids'
candidate_page <- read_html(candidate_url)
candidate_nodes <- html_nodes(candidate_page, 'table')
candidate_list <- html_text(candidate_nodes)
```

My main issue is getting the member IDs. An example ID is A000009. When I use the `gsub` function I lose the leading A in this example. The A is from this candidate's last name (Abercrombie), but I do not know how to add the A back into the member ID. Of course if there's a better way I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got an HTML table, use `html_table` to extract it to a data.frame. You'll need `fill = TRUE`, because the table has extra empty rows inserted between each entry, which you can easily drop afterwards with `tidyr::drop_na`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

page <- 'https://www.congress.gov/help/field-values/member-bioguide-ids' %>% 
    read_html()

members <- page %>% 
    html_node('table') %>% 
    html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
    set_names('member', 'bioguide') %>% 
    drop_na(member) %>%    # remove empty rows inserted in the table
    tbl_df()    # for printing

members
#> # A tibble: 2,243 x 2
#>                                             member bioguide
#>  *                                           <chr>    <chr>
#>  1       Abdnor, James (Republican - South Dakota)  A000009
#>  2         Abercrombie, Neil (Democratic - Hawaii)  A000014
#>  3     Abourezk, James (Democratic - South Dakota)  A000017
#>  4     Abraham, Ralph Lee (Republican - Louisiana)  A000374
#>  5        Abraham, Spencer (Republican - Michigan)  A000355
#>  6         Abzug, Bella S. (Democratic - New York)  A000018
#>  7 Acevedo-Vila, Anibal (Democratic - Puerto Rico)  A000359
#>  8       Ackerman, Gary L. (Democratic - New York)  A000022
#>  9    Adams, Alma S. (Democratic - North Carolina)  A000370
#> 10          Adams, Brock (Democratic - Washington)  A000031
#> # ... with 2,233 more rows
```

The `member` column could be further extracted, if you like.

There are also many other useful sources for this data, some of which correlate it with other useful variables. [This one](https://github.com/unitedstates/congress-legislators/) is well-structured and updated regularly.

Comment: I tried this but it removes half of the members. There should be 4000+, but when we use html_table it cuts it in half. I couldn't figure out why this happened so I am trying other methods.

Comment: There shouldn't be 4000+; that number is inflated by the empty rows.

Comment: But if you really want historical bioguides, all you really need is `members <- read.csv('https://theunitedstates.io/congress-legislators/legislators-historical.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you for the new source. I did not know about that. If i use the read.csv code that you posted in the comments will it continue to update when new candidate's are in office? Also how could you tell there was all the white space? I am not seeing that

Comment: It won't update unless the data has been updated (likely) and you run the code again. You can see the whitespace if you look at the HTML source for the page; there are lots of empty `tr` tags, which is why you need `fill = TRUE` and why there are so many `NA` values in the result of `html_table`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. I have updated this to include separating out the different fields.

```
library('rvest')
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')

candidate_url <- 'https://www.congress.gov/help/field-values/member-bioguide-ids'
candidate_page <- read_html(candidate_url)
candidate_nodes <- html_nodes(candidate_page, 'table')
df.candidates <- as.data.frame(html_table(candidate_nodes, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df.candidates <- df.candidates[!is.na(df.candidates$Member),]

df.candidates <- df.candidates %>%
                 mutate(Party.State = gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(Member, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", Member))[[1]])) %>%
                 separate(Party.State, into = c("Party","State"), sep = " - ") %>%
                 mutate(Full.name = trimws(regmatches(df.candidates$Member, regexpr("^[^\\(]+", df.candidates$Member)))) %>%
                 separate(Full.name, into = c("Last.Name","First.Name","Suffix"), sep = ",", fill = "right") %>%
                 select(First.Name, Last.Name, Suffix, Party, State, Member.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hackish, but if you want to extract the variables using regex here are a few pointers.

```
candidate_list <- unlist(candidate_list)

ID <- regmatches(candidate_list, 
  gregexpr("[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}", candidate_list))

party_state <- regmatches(candidate_list, 
  gregexpr("(?<=\\()[^)]+(?=\\))", candidate_list, perl=TRUE))

names_etc <- strsplit(candidate_list, "[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}")

names <- sapply(names_etc, function(x) sub(" \\([^)]*\\)", "", x))
```